# Server appears to have lost ability to read PHP files with LAMP

Tags: php, lamp, ubuntu-11.10

I have LAMP installed on a PC that is running Ubuntu 11.10.  LAMP was running fine but I had to restart the PC because Unity was messing up (as it often does) and the tool bar had disappeared.  When it started up, I was unable to fire up any php files.  I have a file index.php in /var/www.  It is owned by www-data as is the directory that it is in.  The LAN address of the server is 192.168.1.10.  However when I type 192.168.1.10 into the URL box on Mozilla FireFox, I get

```
Unable to connect      

      Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 192.168.1.10
```

This server is connected to another server on the LAN that has the LAN address 192.168.1.4.  When I type 192.168.1.4 into the Firefow URL box on 192.168.1.10, I see the display associated with index.php on 192.168.1.4.  Why can it not display its own /var/www/index.php?

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated,
Peter.

Comment: On .1.10, show us the output of `netstat --inet -nlp | grep :80`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your web server software (Apache, I assume, since you say LAMP) is running.  With Ubuntu you could run `pidof apache2`, then depending on the output of that, you could try starting it with `service apache2 start` if it is not already running.  If it is running, you would need to post some log output for further troubleshooting.  Apache logs are generally kept in

> /var/log/apache/error_log

Comment: I got not out from "pidof apache2".  With "service apache2 start", I got "apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName".  Thanks, Pater

Comment: I fixed it although the fix doesn't make much sense.  I made a file, /var/www/about.html on the app. server, linked to it (successfully) from the web server and then placed it with /var/www/about.php on the app. server and then linked to the php file from the web server.  After that thing were working fine.  I had also been tinkering with the firewall since I had been making the mistake of calling "iptables-save >iptables.save" not as root so iptables.save ended up being of zero size.  So I had to adjust the firwall to accept tcp packets to and from the web server.  Thanks.